# Order Page - Three Record Insert Tree Different Table How Can I Do it

Tags: laravel

I want to take 3 different form information from a single page for the order and I want to print these 3 different incoming data to different SQL tables.

Order, shipping information and invoice information in three different forms.

```
<form route="{{route('order')}}" methot="POST" id="order">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='11'>
<input type='text' name='book_name' value='example book'>
<input type='text' name='book_price' value='example book price'>
</form>


<form route="{{route('shipping')}}" methot="POST">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='11'>
<input type='text' name='shipping_country' value='example shipping_country'>
<input type='text' name='shipping_address' value='example shipping_address'>
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='How Can take this order value?'>
</form>


<form route="{{route('invoice')}}" methot="POST">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='11'>
<input type='text' name='invoice_identity' value='example identity number'>
<input type='text' name='company_name' value='example company name'>
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='How Can take this order value?'>
</form>
```

What could be a practical method? Another question is how can order_id of the first form on the same page be added to the hidden form in others?

Comment: Will you submit the three forms in three time? or submit first form and get order_id and submit next two forms? can you explain about.

Answer (score 0):

you cant make 3 different from submitting at the same time, you can put all the info in one form, then in the controller, you can save it in 3 different tables,

you should be doing it at the backend in your controller, not in the front end to submit your 3 requests, this is not the right way to do it.